# Problem with simple bash find/mv/rsync script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Been working on this for a bit but I'm having to throw in the towel and ask for help.

Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sets variable to yesterday's date so we can get into the correct directory we need.
YEST=/mnt/cam_recordings/frontcam/5MF50Z6BPDC5286/$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')

# Renames all of yesterday's .jpgs in cam snapshot folders to creation time since
# the camera sometimes duplicates snapshot names.
find $YEST -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
for f; do
    mv -f -- "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jpg"
done' _ {} +


# Copies renamed .jpgs from the cam snapshot folder
# and into a SAMBA share by creating a folder with yesterday's
# date for easy viewing.  
find $YEST -name \*.jpg | rsync -av --files-from - --no-relative / /mnt/camsnaps/$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')
```

The basic of what I need to do are:

1. Create a variable by using find. This variable is the previous day's (Yesterday) camera snapshot folder. That portion of the script seems to work fine.
2. Use `find` to walk through Yesterday's folder structure and then use `mv` to rename all .jpg to their creation date `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jpg`
3. Finally, use `rsync` to copy the files from said folder structure into a newly created folder for easier viewing on the home network via SAMBA.

When the script gets to "step 2" of the script, it renames the files, but deletes them out of the original camera snapshot folder.  I don't want this to happen.  The renamed files should stay where they are.  It also doesn't copy the file into the new folder I want it to in "step 3".  For some reason, it copies the file into the root directory that I'm running the rsync_script.sh from.

So where are my big screw ups here?

Comment: You are missing `=` between `--files-from` and `-`. Should be `--files-from=-`

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't make mutli-line execs with find, it's way harder to read than it needs to be

```sh
files=($(find $YEST -type f -name '*.jpg'))
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    mv -f -- "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jpg"
done
```

2. You are moving files from a full path, e.g., `/mnt/cam_recordings/frontcam/5MF50Z6BPDC5286/blahblahblah.jpg` to just a filename, e.g., `newblahblah.jpg`. `mv` does exactly that. Files without a path are just files in your current path, so that's where it puts them. You need to give them a path, or change what your current path is. Since you want them to stay in their current subdirectory of `$YEST`, we'll have to use `dirname` to grab the directory name and prepend it to the new filename:

```sh
files=($(find $YEST -type f -name '*.jpg'))
for f in $files; do
    mv -f -- "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(date -r "$f" +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jpg"
done
```

Comment: So your number 2 solution doesn't quite work as I intend.  It doesn't leave the files in their current folder.  It moves them up to the root of $YEST.  The files are in deeper nested folders under $YEST.  So I need them to stay in their current folders but be renamed inside of them.  $YEST is simply the starting point.  The files are located within hour and minute directories inside of $YEST.

Comment: @Biggen, edited to work for your desired folder structure

Comment: mv stands for "move".  It _moves_ the file, which means the file is no longer in the old location, it is now in the new location.  If you want the file to be in both the old and new location, use cp (copy) instead.

Comment: @bk_32, I am aware what move does. He is not asking to copy the file, and rename will not work in this case as new name of the file comes from the datestamp of each file.

Comment: I wasn't telling you, I was telling Biggen, because he seemed to not understand why the files were being deleted from his original location.  If you'll notice, my comment was in response to Biggen's comment, not yours.

Comment: @bk_32, I took it as a response to me, since [I was notifed about your comment, and he wasn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/449163). FWIW, he also mentions the files were moved, so I'm not sure there's any confusion on that point.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing you're missing is the `-execdir` option of `find`, which executes with the found file's directory as the "current directory".

```
find $YEST -type f -name '*.jpg' -execdir mv -f {} "$(date -r {} +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jpg" \;

find $YEST -name \*.jpg -execdir cp {} /mnt/camsnaps/$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d') +
```

The `+` version gathers all the files into a single `cp` command.